# MEF .Net Core 1.0 NetStandard 1.6 initialize instance with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mef

I am trying to get an instance of TestPrintTemplate.

I get an exception of 'No Export was found for the contract 'String "SomeData"' when I call container.GetExport(contractName).

How do I initialize the parameter in the TestPrintTemplate() constructor?

```
namespace TestPrintTemplate
{

    [Export("TestPrintTemplate",typeof(IPrintingTemplate))]
    public class TestPrintTemplate : IPrintingTemplate
    {

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TestPrintTemplate([Import("SomeData")]  string data)
        {

        }
        public void Print()
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public interface IPrintingTemplate
    {
        void Print();
    }


        public static T GetExportedValue<T>(this CompositionHost container, string contractName)
        {

            var result = new List<T>();
            string exportedTypeName = typeof(T).FullName;
            var item = container.GetExport<T>(contractName); // I get an exception here
            result.Add((T)item);
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "BinaryFormatter": "1.0.2",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Reflection.Emit": "4.0.1",
    "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0",
    "System.Runtime.Loader": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Composition": "1.0.30",
    "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1",
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1",
    "System.ComponentModel.Primitives": "4.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in IoC container?

Comment: Tseng: Would you be able to provide a code example?

Comment: You used to be able to do that via `ComposeExportedValue` in MEF 1.0 which is not supported yet in MEF 2.0. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443795/702009)  that shows how to work around it for now.